# How to share .avi video on iOS

Tags: ios, video, share, uiactivityviewcontroller, avi

I'm currently working on an IP Camera project. One of the features is that you can download and view recordings from the cameras. You get an url from the camera, download the file and play it using VLC from within the app. 
However, these files are in .avi which is not supported by iTunes. Is it still possible to share .avi files? When I use the following code:

```
NSString *urlToDownload = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@localhost:%@%@", self.activeRecording.urlProtocol, self.activeCamera.localPort, self.activeRecording.urlQuery];
NSString *fullPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[urlToDownload lastPathComponent]];
NSURL *videoUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:fullPath];
self.activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[videoUrl] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:self.activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The url is correct as I can use it to watch the recording. When the share menu opens, it only shows "other" as an option. I'd like to be able to share the video on Facebook and stuff, but at the very least be able to email the video using the share button. Can anyone help me?

tl;dr: Want to share .avi video, doesn't work.

Comment: What if you try NSString *urlStr = [videoUrl absoluteString]; and try passing that along as the activity item?

Comment: Very confusing what is your question.  iTunes and iOS???

Comment: @MikeStrand  If I pass that along as the activity item, I just see this in my mail/facebook/other options: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/00E83A35-1C29-48B7-90C8-F567C5392BBD/tmp/951e33ead6f981e23f32d495a8028d6dfe8e1587bd18d0d15f0eb4338b30b301.avi

Comment: @user523234   iOS has the share button, which has some default functionality. I'd like to use this to share a movie file, but it's in a format that's not recognised by iTunes/iOS (.avi). I was wondering if there was a way to still share this, as Facebook and email should support this format.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to only allow this to be shared over email with the following code:

```
NSString *urlToDownload = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@localhost:%@%@", self.activeRecording.urlProtocol, self.activeCamera.localPort, self.activeRecording.urlQuery];
NSString *fullPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[urlToDownload lastPathComponent]];
NSData *video = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];

MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@ recording", @"-name- recording"), self.activeRecording.name]];

[picker addAttachmentData:video mimeType:@"video/avi" fileName:@"recording.avi"];

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If anyone could find a better solution, that'd be awesome.

Comment: Have you finally found a better solution?

Comment: Nope. Apple is pretty strict in this regard. Something might've changed since I last worked on it as it's been a year or two, but I haven't heard anything at least.